# Play change default packaging system

Tags: scala, playframework, package

I am on play 2.5.2
I know that the default packaging system do expect something like :

```
app/
  controllers/
  models/
  views/
```

But I would like it to be :

```
app/
   foo/
      controllers/
      models/ 
      views/
```

How can I achieve this ?
Over there : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Anatomy
They do say that :

```
Note that in Play, the controllers, models and views package name conventions are now just that and can be changed if needed (such as prefixing everything with com.yourcompany).
```

But that doesn't tell me how.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just place your controllers, models and views in the desired package. No additional configuration is needed. When writing your `routes` file you will have to prefix the entries with the package though. So instead of writing

```
/foo    controllers.FooController.bar()
```

You'll have to write:

```
/foo    foo.controller.FooController.bar()
```

Comment: Ok, that's exactly what I've, but it seems that no packages are recognized, which probably means that my issue is coming from a missing library or something

Comment: Make sure that you don't have any issues in your controllers, views and so on (wrong package declaration in the controller file after moving it or similar things). When there are issues in a controller the routes are not generated and subsequently not recognized in the routes file. You should be able to compile without errors (e.g. via `sbt clean compile`).

Comment: @user1058398 could you perhaps add a stack track to your question? That might help analysis.